# Change text box in checkout page in mageno- which page is to edit?

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I want to change the `input type text` of the `Quantity` to `drop down box` in `checkout page` in **Magento**. For this which page is needed to change?? I need the page to change. Please help me..

I found `app\design\frontend\mytheme\mytheme\template\checkout\cart.phtml` . But there I can't find the required text box for Quantity.

Please refer the image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The file you are looking for is `app/design/frontend/mytheme/mytheme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` and the line you are looking for is at the line 181 in my 1.9.1.0 version of Magento.

For further reference and to easily find file on Magento, please have a look at **Template Path Hints**, when logged in your admin panel, go to **System** > **Configuration** and there, under **Developper** section, click on the **Advanced** tab.
In the upper left corner of the admin path, you do have a **Current configuration scope** selector, in there select the store view you are in and wait for the page to reload, then open up the **Debug** section and select **Yes** for **Template Path Hints**. Then reload your frontend page and see the magic happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In default.phtml I can't echo the product attributes. For example I have weight(system attr), shape(newly added attribute) attributes can't echo them. How can do this? Plz suggest...